# Select a particular task from other yaml file - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have multiple yaml files in role and I want to import single task from other yaml file.

Say, I have 2 yaml files. A.yml and B.yml with following tasks
and I am trying to inclde a task from A.yml into B.yml and I don't want all other tasks of A.yml be included.

```
A.yml
  taks1:
  task2:

B.yml
  task3:
  include: task2(from A.yml)
```

How would I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible.

You should define task you want to reuse (task2) as separate YAML file and include it in A.yml and B.yml.